# How to set the CSS attribute based on the font awesome class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have the html block that displays the borders incorrectly. This is happening when the ul block is expanded. When the ul block is collapsed the border bottom is displaying correctly. Here is my example:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    SIDEBAR.ExpandCollapse("Auto");
});

const SIDEBAR = {};

SIDEBAR.ToggleContent = function($link_item) {
    let section_id = $link_item.attr("data-id"),
        $sContents = $("#section_" + section_id);

    if ( $sContents.css("display") != "none" ) {
        $sContents.css("display","none");
        $link_item.find('i').removeClass("fa-folder-open").addClass("fa-folder");
    } else {
        $sContents.css("display","");
        $link_item.find('i').removeClass("fa-folder").addClass("fa-folder-open");
    }
};

$(".sidebar").on("click", ".toggle-menu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let $link_item = $(this);
    SIDEBAR.ToggleContent($link_item);
});

SIDEBAR.ExpandCollapse = function(action) {
    let $menu_items = $(".parent-menu, .child-menu");

    $menu_items.each((index, element) => {
        let $curr_section = $(element),
            $folder = $curr_section.prev(),
            expand_val = null,
            root_val = null;

        switch (action) {
            case "Expand":
                expand_val = "Yes";
                break;
            case "Collapse":
                expand_val = "No";
                break;
            default:
                expand_val = $curr_section.attr("data-expand");
                if ( !expand_val ) expand_val = "Yes";
        }

        root_val = $curr_section.attr("data-root");
        if (root_val && root_val == "Yes") expand_val = "Yes";

        if ( expand_val == "No" ) {
            $curr_section.css("display","none");
            $folder.find("i").removeClass("fa-folder-open").addClass("fa-folder");
        } else {
            $curr_section.css("display","");
            $folder.find("i").removeClass("fa-folder").addClass("fa-folder-open");
        }
    });
};

$(".sidebar").on("click", ".collapse-menu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let action = $(this).attr("data-action");
    SIDEBAR.ExpandCollapse(action);
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #0071bc;
  color: #fff;
  height: calc(100vh - 98px);
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 9pt !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
}
.link-item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link-item:hover,
.link-item:focus {
  color: #ff0;
}

.expand-collapse {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-folder:before {
  color: #DBDB2A !important;
}

.fa-folder-open:before {
  color: #DBDB2A !important;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav.parent-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav.child_menu li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav.child_menu>li>a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level>a {
  padding: 4px 20px;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:before {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: auto;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 8px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  width: 8px;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:after {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:last-child:after {
  bottom: 50%;
}
/*
ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:last-child:after {
  bottom: 83%;
}
*/
ul.nav.child-menu li>a {
  padding: 2px 40px;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li:before {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: auto;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  width: 9px;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li:after {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li:last-child::after {
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav grandparent-menu pl-1 pr-1">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-menu" title="Management" data-id="m"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-folder"></i> Management</a>
      <ul class="nav parent-menu" id="section_m" data-root="Yes" data-expand="Yes" style="display: none;">

        <li class="first-level">
          <a class="toggle-menu" href="#" title="Admin" data-id="admin"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Admin</a>
          <ul class="nav child-menu" id="section_admin" data-expand="No" style="display: none;">
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Parameters"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Parameters</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Schema"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Schema</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Menu"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="first-level">
          <a class="toggle-menu" href="#" title="Control" data-id="control"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Control</a>
          <ul class="nav child-menu" id="section_control" data-expand="No" style="display: none;">
            <li><a class="link-item" title="User"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> User</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Role"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Role</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my example above everything works fine except the case when you expand the last child. In that case the border line on the left is extending more than it should. I figure out what percentage it should be in case when the last child section is expanded and collapsed (collapsed bottom:50% / expanded bottom:83%). I still didn't find a way to fix this issue. I would like to use CSS for this solution if possible. Basically to detect when the last child folder is open/closed and set the attribute. If anyone have solution for this issue please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a more minimal example?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev not sure what I can minimize. The issue is with the last child in the parent block. If you expand control folder the left border is not ending properly. That's all I need to be fixed.

Comment: You are going to need some jQuery for the desired outcome. `first-level` elements do not have any indicator the CSS can use to determine if it's expanded or not. You'll need a class or attribute to add to `first-level` that the CSS can then target the appropriate styling.

Comment: @macintosh Can you please provide an example?

Comment: The problem is that the vertical white bar is set as the left border of a pseudo element on an element which expands as the user clicks down the tree. The relevant CSS is at ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:after

Comment: @AHaworth I already found the issue. Is there a way to fix this with CSS? Or should I consider moving the pseudo element in a different place? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the line is going below where it's expected is because the last child folder (control) is growing when its children are displayed. The way to solve this is forcing the last folder to not grow. It will still display the children.

Just add this to the css:

```
.nav.parent-menu>li:last-child {
    height: 25px;
}
```

This is the code snippet with the fix:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    SIDEBAR.ExpandCollapse("Auto");
});

const SIDEBAR = {};

SIDEBAR.ToggleContent = function($link_item) {
    let section_id = $link_item.attr("data-id"),
        $sContents = $("#section_" + section_id);

    if ( $sContents.css("display") != "none" ) {
        $sContents.css("display","none");
        $link_item.find('i').removeClass("fa-folder-open").addClass("fa-folder");
    } else {
        $sContents.css("display","");
        $link_item.find('i').removeClass("fa-folder").addClass("fa-folder-open");
    }
};

$(".sidebar").on("click", ".toggle-menu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let $link_item = $(this);
    SIDEBAR.ToggleContent($link_item);
});

SIDEBAR.ExpandCollapse = function(action) {
    let $menu_items = $(".parent-menu, .child-menu");

    $menu_items.each((index, element) => {
        let $curr_section = $(element),
            $folder = $curr_section.prev(),
            expand_val = null,
            root_val = null;

        switch (action) {
            case "Expand":
                expand_val = "Yes";
                break;
            case "Collapse":
                expand_val = "No";
                break;
            default:
                expand_val = $curr_section.attr("data-expand");
                if ( !expand_val ) expand_val = "Yes";
        }

        root_val = $curr_section.attr("data-root");
        if (root_val && root_val == "Yes") expand_val = "Yes";

        if ( expand_val == "No" ) {
            $curr_section.css("display","none");
            $folder.find("i").removeClass("fa-folder-open").addClass("fa-folder");
        } else {
            $curr_section.css("display","");
            $folder.find("i").removeClass("fa-folder").addClass("fa-folder-open");
        }
    });
};

$(".sidebar").on("click", ".collapse-menu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let action = $(this).attr("data-action");
    SIDEBAR.ExpandCollapse(action);
});
```

```css
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #0071bc;
  color: #fff;
  height: calc(100vh - 98px);
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 9pt !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar a {
  color: #fff;
}
.link-item {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link-item:hover,
.link-item:focus {
  color: #ff0;
}

.expand-collapse {
  border: 1px solid white;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-folder:before {
  color: #DBDB2A !important;
}

.fa-folder-open:before {
  color: #DBDB2A !important;
}

.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.nav>li>a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav.parent-menu>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav.child_menu li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav.child_menu>li>a {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level>a {
  padding: 4px 20px;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:before {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: auto;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 8px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  width: 8px;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:after {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

ul.nav.parent-menu li.first-level:last-child:after {
  bottom: 50%;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li>a {
  padding: 2px 40px;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li:before {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: auto;
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  width: 9px;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li:after {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  left: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

ul.nav.child-menu li:last-child::after {
  bottom: 50%;
}

/* BEGIN SOLUTION */
.nav.parent-menu>li:last-child {
    height: 25px;
}
/* END SOLUTION */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul class="nav grandparent-menu pl-1 pr-1">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle-menu" title="Management" data-id="m"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-folder"></i> Management</a>
      <ul class="nav parent-menu" id="section_m" data-root="Yes" data-expand="Yes" style="display: none;">

        <li class="first-level">
          <a class="toggle-menu" href="#" title="Admin" data-id="admin"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Admin</a>
          <ul class="nav child-menu" id="section_admin" data-expand="No" style="display: none;">
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Parameters"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Parameters</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Schema"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Schema</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Menu"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="first-level">
          <a class="toggle-menu" href="#" title="Control" data-id="control"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Control</a>
          <ul class="nav child-menu" id="section_control" data-expand="No" style="display: none;">
            <li><a class="link-item" title="User"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> User</a></li>
            <li><a class="link-item" title="Role"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i> Role</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```